# Truncate search query text

Tags: catalogsearch, search, search-terms

I want to substring the query terms in my magento searches.

Example: the user type "dogs" in the magento search input and the results actually search for "dog".

Is there a way to change that?

Where should I put something really simple as:

```
$text = substr ( $text , ..., ...);
```

Which core code should I look for?

In addition, I prefer that the user will be able to see the whole text typed in the input field while displaying search results page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the search term is returned from the following function 
**getEscapedQueryText()** in **app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data.php**

Override that helper. Thats all.